# boost T_CONTLINE token doesn't work

Tags: c++, boost

What i think is that there is a bug in the boost token ids. But I'm not sure.
The boost token iterators are not able to detect the `T_CONTLINE` token which is '\ \' followed by '\n' See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/wave/doc/token_ids.html

For the sample test, I have a test file: testfile.h

```
  1 #define Funtion(x) X + \
  2                       Y
  3 
  4 #define MYVAR 100+\
  5               200
```

And here is the program which looks for the T_CONTLINE

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <fstream>
  3 
  4 #include <boost/wave/cpplexer/cpp_lex_token.hpp>
  5 #include <boost/wave/cpplexer/cpp_lex_iterator.hpp>
  6 
  7 typedef boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_token<> token_type;
  8 typedef boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_iterator<token_type> token_iterator;
  9 typedef token_type::position_type position_type;
 10 
 11 int main()
 12 {
 13   const char* infile = "testfile.h";
 14   std::string instr;
 15   std::ifstream gmstream(infile);
 16   if(!gmstream.is_open()) {
 17       std::cerr << "Could not open file: "<< infile<<"\n";
 18   }
 19   gmstream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
 20   instr = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(gmstream.rdbuf()),
 21       std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
 22 
 23   position_type pos(infile);
 24   token_iterator  it = token_iterator(instr.begin(), instr.end(), pos,
 25       boost::wave::language_support(
 26         boost::wave::support_cpp|boost::wave::support_option_long_long));
 27   token_iterator end = token_iterator();
 28 
 29   boost::wave::token_id id = *it;
 30 
 31   while(it!=end) {
 32     if(id == boost::wave::T_CONTLINE) {
 33       std::cout<<"Found Contline";
 34     }
 35     ++it;
 36     id = *it;
 37   }
 38 return 0;
 39 }
```

But I don't get any output.

I'm using boost_1_47_1, and gcc-4.5

**EDIT:**
Actually there was a similar bug-report posted here:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5569

See the changelog: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/wave/ChangeLog

This bug is reported to be solved with the latest boost 1.47.0 So i installed the latest boost 1.47.0 but still the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this token is not exposed on the iterator level, it is just handled internally very early in the processing. It's not a bug, but expected behavior. I will add a note to the documentation.

Comment: thanks... but i need to identify the T_CONTLINE. How do i do this. The problem is when i read the tokens into a stringstream and then rewrite them into another file, all the T_CONTLINE gets lost and gets replaced with space.. due to which the formatting of the macros gets affected badly.

Comment: I added a new flag to Wave: support_option_emit_contnewlines, which allows the T_CONTLINE tokens to be emitted by the library. The only caveat is that this is currently only supported by the SLex custom lexer module. You will need to use that for now.

Comment: thanks i saw the update. since i am using the boost_wave now, what i think is switching to SLex will take some time. Is there a chance that you'd update the boost_wave's lexer also.